# Angular 2 [hidden] while still taking up DOM space

Tags: css, angular

What's the equivalent of this but still takes up space in the DOM?

```
[hidden]="findForm.controls.categories.valid || findForm.controls.categories.pristine"
```

tried a few things including this:

```
[ngClass]="{no-error: 'findForm.controls.categories.valid || findForm.controls.categories.pristine'}"
```

css:

```
.no-error { visibility: hidden }
```

But nothing is working so far.

Comment: try this,
      [ngClass]="{'no-error':  findForm.controls.categories.valid || findForm.controls.categories.pristine}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Had the single quotes around the condition, but they go around the class name.

```
[ngClass]="{'no-error': findForm.controls.categories.valid || findForm.controls.categories.pristine}"
```